# Edit file inside an apex_payload.img

Tags: editing

There is a file named com.google.android.tzdata2.apex in my android phone
I open it in linux ubuntu, and there was a file inside it named apex_payload.img, i open this in ubuntu and a /dev/loop13 created that shows file in read-only mode

Is it possible to edit files inside apex_payload.img?
There is a tzdata file that i wanted to change